# "Debug" and "Release" configuration difference for .NET MAUI project

Tags: .net, visual-studio

For my .NET MAUI app I have identical declarations for Debug and Release configs in csproj file:

For "Release" configuation:

```xml
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
        <Optimize>False</Optimize>
        <Deterministic>True</Deterministic>
        <MtouchLink>Full</MtouchLink>
        <MtouchUseLlvm>False</MtouchUseLlvm>
        <MtouchNoSymbolStrip>True</MtouchNoSymbolStrip>
        <AdditionalArgs>-v -v -v -v</AdditionalArgs>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

And for "Debug" configuration:

```xml
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
        <Optimize>False</Optimize>
        <Deterministic>True</Deterministic>
        <MtouchLink>Full</MtouchLink>
        <MtouchUseLlvm>False</MtouchUseLlvm>
        <MtouchNoSymbolStrip>True</MtouchNoSymbolStrip>
        <AdditionalArgs>-v -v -v -v</AdditionalArgs>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

As you can see those declarations are identical. But when I ran iOS app in "Debug" config it runs on actual device, but when I ran the same app I get linker issue and app is crashed without any error message.

Two questions:

If configuration declarations are identical ('Link All' set in both configs) what's the difference between Debug and Release configs in this case?

How can I determine why app is crashing running on "Release" config, while it works on "Debug" config with the same options set as for "Release"?

Comment: Looks like a known issue and can be resolved by creating a new project and copying all code into the new project. I guess they published a bad template in the past? 
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8928

Comment: @ScottSolmer thank you for the insight. Appreciate it. Will check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I added the following declaration to the csproj file it solved the issue:

```xml
    <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios'))">
        <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

I do not understand why did it help for this particular case, but it helped.
If you have the same issue with .NET MAUI project and my way did not help, please check this discussion: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8928