# .NET MAUI Debug Build works fine but Release Build fails

Tags: c#, maui, release-mode

I'm trying to publish my MAUI project in release mode for iOS and Android and right now in Debug mode I can get the app on my iPhone, as well as launch the Android emulator and have that work. But when I go into release mode it just... doesn't work? There's not even any errors it just builds for like 10x longer than normal and then says "Deployment Failed".

I tried to build my project in release mode (both iOS and Android, both failed) and I expected that it would be the same as Debug mode and just work. But it just says Deployment Failed with nothing really in the errors box.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75756980/debug-and-release-configuration-difference-for-net-maui-project/75757488#75757488 If it does not help, probably you have linker issue, check this then: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/linking?tabs=vs

Comment: Please answer your own question and post information what helped to resolve your case. It will help SO users to find the solution if they experience the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: Did you reach some resolution?